# transposing data with missing records in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, transpose

I'm trying to create a rolling 8-day report (TODAY()-8 to TODAY()-1). For each BY variable combinations, there aren't always data for each date. PROC TRANSPOSE or ARRAY doesn't put it in the correct "day" variable.

Here's a sample of the records:

```
FacilityNM    MetricGrp    MetricNM      Date      Value
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS   6/29/23      50
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS   6/30/23      41
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS   7/3/23        5 
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS   7/5/23       30
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS   7/6/23       58
PB            Volume       ED Visits     6/29/23     180
PB            Volume       ED Visits     6/30/23     210
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/1/23      160
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/2/23      170
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/3/23      185
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/4/23      140
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/5/23      180
PB            Volume       ED Visits     7/6/23      180
```

What I want:

```
FacilityNM MetricGrp  MetricNM    Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7 Day8 
PB         Surgery    Cases - SDS   50   41              5        30   58 
PB         Volume     ED Visits    180  210  160  170  185  140  180  180
```

What I get using Proc Transpose or ARRAY:

```
FacilityNM    MetricGrp    MetricNM      Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7 Day8
PB            Surgery      Cases - SDS     50   41    5   30   58
PB            Volume       ED Visits      180  210  160  170  185  140  180  180
```

How can I get what I want?

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Either method will work if you just first calculate the relative day number before hand.  But what is the BASE date for your day numbering?  Is the first date per BY group? Or the first per some larger grouping variable such as SUBJECT_ID?

```
data grouping;
  set have;
  by FacilityNM MetricGrp MetricNM Date ;
  if first.MetricNM then basedate=date;
  retain basedate;
  day = date - basedate + 1;
run;
proc transpose data=grouping out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=day;
   by FacilityNM MetricGrp MetricNM ;
   id day;
   var value;
run;
```

If the goal is instead to just fill in the gaps in the orignal series then make a "skeleton" file with every possible date and metric and merge it with the original file.

```
proc sql ;
  create table metrics as select distinct FacilityNM,MetricGrp, MetricNM from have;
  create table date_range as select min(date) as d1,max(date) as d2 from have;
quit;
data skeleton ;
   set metrics;
   if _n_=1 then set date_range;
   value = 0;
   do date=d1 to d2;
     output;
   end;
   format date date9. ;
   drop d1 d2;
 run;
 data want ;
    merge skeleton have;
    by FacilityNM MetricGrp MetricNM date ;
 run;
```

Comment: This is a daily summary that shows metrics for the previous 8 days. For each facility/grp/metric combination, there may or may not be data for all the dates (e.g., no procedures done in Same Day Surgery (SDS) on weekends/holidays). So, for those dates that are missing, I want to insert a record with the missing date and 0 for the metric value.  In the example, for Surg Cases - SDS, I want to add records for 7/1, 7/2, and 7/4 with 0s for Value.

Comment: If you want to fill in the missing dates then do that before transposing. (Why are you transposing anyway?)